# Is it possible to get JSContext without waiting webViewDidLoadFinish?

Tags: android, ios, javascriptcore

When I want to inject some JS methods, I have to do it in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`
If I get the context in `-webViewDidStartLoad` the context will be different from the one got in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

Is there another method to do it without waiting? 
I've found that Android Injection code, they totally don't need so much work as iOS do

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    JSContext *context = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    JSContext *context = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
```